# Problema al migrar tablas con Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-6

Apenas acabo de instalar Laravel 6 en mi macOS Catalina y estoy practicando migrar tablas, pero al querer intentar hacer una simple migración de tablas, el "php artisan migrate" me arroja un error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = pizza and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

E podido encontrar varias soluciones comúnes a este problema pero ni una de las siguientes me ha funcionado:

1. Cambiar `DB_HOST a "localhost"`
2. Incluir `port=>env(3306)`, pero esto ya está incluido en mi proyecto
3. Incluir `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` en "AppServiceProvider.php" y dentro de este archivo también incluir `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` en la función  "public function boot()"

Lamentablemente ni una de estas soluciones a tenido efecto, tal vez no estoy realizando bien la operación, me refiero a que después de incluir estos cambios tenga que "decirle" a php artisan o a Laravel que "ejecute" los cambios o que guarde de alguna manera dichos comandos, pero hasta el momento nada de esto me ha funcionado, muchas gracias espero poder encontrar la respuesta.

Adjunto imagen.
[image: problema laravel]

.env

```
APP_NAME=LARAPP
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:8caA7+XORE9PodGn3kF6nZeQByW4sAI3+z699oWr2Ew=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pizza
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Podrias indicar si tu archivo `.env` esta bien configurada? y que base de datos utilizas

Comment: No sé a que te puedas referir con "bien configurada", utilizo MySQL, voy abriendo el primer proyecto, si deseas saber acerca de una variable en específico o prefieres ver el archivo, házmelo saber para poder agregarlo a la pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Ya configuraste el archivo `.env`? podrias mostrarlo.

Comment: Lo único que cambie en este archivo fue DB_DATABASE a el nombre que estoy usando para prácticar, está incluido ya. Saludos.

Comment: dos ultimas preguntas, 1.- ¿Tu base de datos "pizza" esta creada?,2.-¿Tu base de datos no tiene contraseña?

Comment: Mi base de datos no tiene una contraseña y si está creada, la añadí vía myphpadmin y no tiene columnas, simplemente la añadi por el nombre pero si se encuentra creada.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105028/discussion-between-eduardo-and-shassain).